# Dismiss modal view causes issue with ShareKit Email and Twitter

Tags: iphone

I have a pop up game view and then a Sharekit on top of that. 
When I send mail through ShareKit Email or Twitter and then did dismiss the game view
through [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES], next time the game view brought up again, then sharekit Email and Twitter view have issue popping up.

I think the dissmodalviewcontroller messed the sharekit up, but I need that to dismiss my game view through dismissModalViewController.

any ideas to make those two compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that, try: `[self removeFromSuperView]` or `popViewController` (self).

Comment: The game is a UIViewController, When I did [self.view removefromsuperview] I got a completely white scene.   DismissviewController would nicely dismiss this game view controller.

Comment: Instead of self.view, try inserting the name of the ShareKit view.

Comment: The sharekit is self contained. Once I hit the sendmail button it automatically dismiss its modal view I don't have to touch that part. So now what's left now is my game view controller and its view. And there's more viewcontrollers and view beneath the game vc.

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: iOS 4.2.1   I doubt thats version issue.

Comment: Actually, ShareKit is kind of old, and there have been version issues.